# how to create private repo using linux or cli in docker hub

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, devops, dockerhub

I'm attempting to push a Docker image to a private repository on Docker Hub without manual intervention, as it's integrated with Jenkins. Despite trying Docker commands and sending cURL requests to the Docker API, I haven't been successful.

The goal is to automate the image push to the private repository without relying on manual creation through the console. Any insights or guidance on achieving this within a Jenkins pipeline or through automated means would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the approaches I've attempted so far:

Utilizing Docker commands.
Sending cURL requests to the Docker API.
However, these methods haven't yielded the desired outcome. Any suggestions or code snippets demonstrating the correct procedure would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: What is the issue/error you are facing? Using Docker CLI commands should allow you to push your images into private repos without any problems, so what is the issue with that approach?

Answer (score -2):

1. Start by installing and running Jenkins in Docker.
2. Use the Dockerfile to build the Jenkins Docker image.
3. Start the Docker image and launched a Jenkins Docker container.
4. Follow the steps of unlocking Jenkins and creating the first admin user.
5. Add the Docker Hub and GitHub Credentials to Jenkins for authentication.
6. Create project files (Jenkinsfile and a Dockerfile) and pushed them to GitHub.
7. Use a Jenkinsfile to run the Jenkins Pipeline
8. Push a Docker image to Docker Hub.